# How to display this properly in Android TextView?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I got this string from API:

â€¢

and it is supposed to be shown as:

•

Both decode UTF-8 it (I am not sure what encoding `â€¢` is) , or Html.fromHTML does not work for me.